# difference between get_template_directory_uri() and bloginfo('template_directory')

Tags: php, wordpress

iam new to wordpress...now am trying to develop a wordpress theme from my existing html template.And iam confused with difference between get_template_directory_uri() and bloginfo('template_directory') .. From some other site i found that both are doing same.  can anyone help for knowing the difference? if both are same please let me know which is best to use

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between the two (prior to WP 2.6, template_directory generated a local path, but now, it's the same). `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` and `get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )` simply return `get_template_directory_uri()`.

See this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72731/35498) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using get_template_directory_uri() to enqueue a script with the correct path
bloginfo() is use to displays information about your site like bloginfo('url'), bloginfo('name'), bloginfo('description'), bloginfo('template_url')

Answer (score 0):

Another difference you can see that get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) works without echo so you couldn't take it into variable if need whereas you can get_template_directory_uri() into variable. So according to your task differentiation, you can chose one of them.